# How to use subprocess to filter output of Windows nslookup to only display name?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have a script I've found online and started modifying. It scans a network for up hosts, and now I want it to use the nslookup command to display the hostname under the IP is up message.

Program:

```
# Import modules
import subprocess
import ipaddress

# Prompt the user to input a network address
net_addr = input("Enter a network address in CIDR format(ex.192.168.1.0/24): ")

# Create the network
ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(net_addr)

# Get all hosts on that network
all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())

# Configure subprocess to hide the console window
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

# For each IP address in the subnet, 
# run the ping command with subprocess.popen interface
for i in range(len(all_hosts)):
    output = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '1', str(all_hosts[i])], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=info).communicate()[0]

    if "Destination host unreachable" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        None
    elif "Request timed out" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        None
    else:
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Online",)
        #Runs nslookup for online host, need to figure how to filter it to just show name
        subprocess.Popen(['nslookup', str(all_hosts[i])])
print('Scan complete.')
```

Currently it works, but it is outputting the entire output from nslookup.

In windows command line, `nslookup X.X.X.X | find /I "Name: "`.

Gives me what I want.

I have tried adding as a string after the list is inputted, but that does not work.

I used `shlex` to split the `args` and tried that, but it's giving me the instructions for how to use `nslookup` when I do.

Example:

```
>>> command_line = input()
nslookup 8.8.8.8 | find /I "Name: "
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print(args)
['nslookup', '8.8.8.8', '|', 'find', '/I', 'Name: ']
>>> subprocess.Popen(['nslookup', '8.8.8.8', '|', 'find', '/I', 'Name: '])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x03747208>
>>> Usage:
   nslookup [-opt ...]             # interactive mode using default server
   nslookup [-opt ...] - server    # interactive mode using 'server'
   nslookup [-opt ...] host        # just look up 'host' using default server
   nslookup [-opt ...] host server # just look up 'host' using 'server'
```

Is there a simple way for me to just get the name?

What I would like is

```
X.X.X.X is Online
Name: hostname from nslookup
```

as the output.

**

### Thanks to martineau, here is the fixed code that runs as I intended:

**

```
# Import modules
import subprocess
import ipaddress

# Prompt the user to input a network address
net_addr = input("Enter a network address in CIDR format(ex.192.168.1.0/24): ")

# Create the network
ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(net_addr)

# Get all hosts on that network
all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())

# Configure subprocess to hide the console window
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

# For each IP address in the subnet, 
# run the ping command with subprocess.popen interface
for i in range(len(all_hosts)):
    output = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '1', str(all_hosts[i])], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=info).communicate()[0]

    if "Destination host unreachable" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        None
    elif "Request timed out" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        None
    else:
        print(str(all_hosts[i]))
        #Runs nslookup for online host, prints the host name is online
        args =['nslookup', str(all_hosts[i])]
        completed = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        onlineName = [line for line in completed.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines() if "Name: " in line]
        if onlineName:
            print(onlineName[0].split()[1], 'is Online \n')       
print('Scan complete.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do command-line piping in conjunction with `Popen` like that — but fortunately you don't really need it because Python can easily do the text processing that the Windows `find` command does.

This demonstrates what I mean:

```
import subprocess

args = ['nslookup', '8.8.8.8']
completed = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
online = [line for line in completed.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines() if "Name:" in line]
if online:
    print(online[0].split()[1], 'is online')
```

Comment: excellent work. I need to beef up my python. I knew it must have to do with PIPE / stdout but I don't know enough to understand the subprocess documentation. I will go back to studying, and continue to review your code as I gain more understanding. Thanks so much.

Comment: Alexander: That's good to hear. I've found the book _The Python 3 Standard Library by Example_ by Doug Hellmann and associated [PyMOTW-3](https://pymotw.com/3/) website a very good way to learn about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to assign the subprocess output to a variable and split.

```
# Import modules
import subprocess
import ipaddress

# Prompt the user to input a network address
net_addr = input("Enter a network address in CIDR format(ex.192.168.1.0/24): ")

# Create the network
ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(net_addr)

# Get all hosts on that network
all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())

# Configure subprocess to hide the console window
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

# For each IP address in the subnet,
# run the ping command with subprocess.popen interface
for i in range(len(all_hosts)):
    output = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '1', str(all_hosts[i])],
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=info).communicate()[0]

    if "Destination host unreachable" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        None
    elif "Request timed out" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        None
    else:
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Online",)
        #Runs nslookup for online host, need to figure how to filter it to just    show name
        process=subprocess.Popen(['nslookup', str(all_hosts[i])],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        output=(process.communicate()[0])
        print(type(output))
        line=output.split("\n")
        print(line[0].split(":")[1], 'is online')


print('Scan complete.')
```